Dynamic trigger rule?
I have a DAG where I have 3 sensors and a data processing task that must run after the sensors have completed successfully.
Something like this:


sensorA -->
           \
sensorB -->-+- data processing
           /
sensorC -->


The twist is: the downstream task won't always need to wait on all 3 sensors - it might only need to wait on 1 or 2 of them. Which sensors to wait on will get decided outside of the DAG, based on user interactions.
I know I can use a PythonBranchOperator to read the external value which indicates which sensor(s) should be chosen, and I can use trigger rules to ensure that the data processing task will run after at least one sensor finishes correctly, but I realized that I can't tell the data processing step which sensors need to complete.
So now I'm thinking I need to do something more like this:

BranchOperator ->--+--> Sensor A ---------------------------->-+ 
                   |                                           |
                   +--> Sensor B ---------------------------->-+
                   |                                           |
                   +--> Sensor C ---------------------------->-+
                   |                                           |
                   +--> Sensor A --> Sensor B --------------->-+
                   |                                           |
                   +--> Sensor A --> Sensor C --------------->-+
                   |                                           |
                   +--> Sensor B --> Sensor C --------------->-+
                   |                                           |
                   +--> Sensor A --> Sensor B --> Sensor C -->-+--> data processing

And the data processing step has the trigger rule "none_failed_min_one_success".
But this feels rather clunky and awkward, and since I know there will be more than just these 3 sensors in the future, it's just going to get more cluttered.
Is there a more elegant way for the data processing step's trigger rule to be aware of which sensors it should wait for?

I'm not sure why you need the extra complexity. If the PythonBranchOperator has the knowledge which sensor to execute then it can simply return their task_ids. The other branches will be skipped. so your original design would work just fine with branch operator as the root node.

@EladKalif But if the BranchOperator returns ['SensorA', 'SensorC'], I want to wait until both of them complete. I'm concerned that "none_failed_min_one_success" will let the downstream job start when SensorA has fired, but SensorC has not - this will result in processing data with fresh "A"-type data but stale "C"-type data.
I think my second diagram avoids this situation, but I'm concerned about the complexity as more sensors are added (already we have > 3 and this project is still in the design stage).
I guess I'm looking for something like trigger_rule=['SensorA','SensorC']

I dont think this can happen. You can easily create a test for it. Your send digram is very complex and can not be scaled. What will you do with 10 sensors?  Please check what I suggested. If it doesnt work I will restart the discussion around dynamic trigger rules  which decided as won't fix a while ago https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/17010  The dag authoring experiance should be clean and easy. If it is not then we are missing something in the project and we should adress it.

@EladKalif Yeah that's what I'm concerned with: there will probably be more sensors as the upstream teams gather up all of the things that need their own sensors. User interactions will result in a need to run the data processing task, but only for "fresh" data, which is why I need to wait on some specific sensors and ignore others, and which sensors to wait on/ignore will change. Creating branches for all possible sensor combinations can be done but it seems too complex and I was hoping for a better solution. I also realise that this is probably not a typical scenario for most DAG authors.

@EladKalif Wait a minute - do you mean that if my branch operator returns ['SensorA','SensorC'] then I don't have to worry about Sensor B because my task will automatically ignore Sensor B? If so then I think I have nothing to worry about: I might have misunderstood the original documentation!
But I'm still confused about which trigger rule I need to use to ensure that the data processing step waits for Sensor A and Sensor C to be triggered.

Exactly. BranchOpeartor will automatically set SensorB to skip. Thus the question now is if SensorA and SensorC will finish with success or failure. Either way you are safe. This is why I said my idea should work.

@EladKalif Ok, I think I misunderstood how that trigger rule would work in this case. I'll run some tests just to check but thanks for helping clear this up.

A task trigger rule checks the status of it's direct upstream tasks. in your case (first diagram) data_processing will check the statuses of sensorA, sensorB, sensorC. Thus if you will set BranchOpeartor as root : Branch >> [sensorA, sensorB, sensorC] >> data_processing The branch operator will make sure to set skip on the sensors that are not eligible for running according to whatever task_ids you return so if branch returns  [sensorB, sensorC], then sensorA is skipped and sensorB, sensorC will be either in success or failure which is what data_processing is expecting.

You actually figured out the right components to solve your issue but you misinterpret how branching works.
There is no need to specify all possible combination. The branch operator just need to return the task_id(s) of the sensors required for running the others will be automatically skipped.
Code template example:
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

with DAG(
    dag_id="sensors",
    start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False

) as dag:

    @task.branch
    def branch_func():
        # Replace with logic how to choose the sensors you want to run
        return ["sensorA", "SensorB"]

    a = EmptyOperator(task_id="sensorA") # Replace with Sensor
    b = EmptyOperator(task_id="SensorB") # Replace with Sensor
    c = EmptyOperator(task_id="SensorC") # Replace with Sensor

    data_processing = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="data_processing",
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED_MIN_ONE_SUCCESS
    )

    branch_func() >> [a, b, c] >> data_processing

This will give:

Which is expected. data_processing is eligible to run because sensorA and sensorB finished with success and sensorC is skipped.
To simulate what happens in case of failure I manually set SensorA as failed and rerun data_processing:

as you can see in this case data_processing is set to upsream_failed status which means that the task can not run because upstream dependency does not met.
In case that branch returns empty list (all sensors are to be skipped) then data_processing is also skipped.

